# Can PGA be cascaded to amplify small signal?

Tags: amplifier

I need amplify small 50Hz AC signal. The range is from sub mV to hunderds of mV. Can I use multiple cascaded PGAs?

Something like: signal_source => PGA205 => PGA204 => PGA204....,

Comment: Yes, but watch out for the noise: noise in the first amplifier will also be amplified by the subsequent ones. You would be better off with fixed low noise amplifier (LNA) on the front.

Comment: How much noise can you tolerate? What PGA are you planning to use?

Comment: @gbulmer, TI's PGA204 and PGA205

Comment: Thanks. I guess I wondered why the lower-gain first, so assumed I was mistaken. So now, I ask, why the low gain PGA205 first, rather than the PGA204?

Comment: @gbulmer: PGA204 has smaller gain (x1, x2, x4, x8), and higher GBP. I think the front of the signal chain will have more noise than the following stage. If i want amplify the signal to 200 times, there will be two possible configurationgs: 1> Put PGA204 first and configure it to x100, and then PGA205 with gain x2. 2> Reverse the former configuration, with PGA205 first and PGA204 following. I think there will be more noise enter the signal chain in the first configuration. Am i right ? Any suggestiongs?

Comment: "PGA204 has smaller gain (x1, x2, x4, x8)". According to [TI's PGA204 PGA205 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pga204.pdf) "PGA204: G=1, 10, 100, 1000V/V" and "PGA205: G=1, 2, 4, 8V/V", not the other way round. So I believe your assumption in that part of the comment is incorrect, and PGA204 first would be better. I think Spehro Pefhany and pjc50's comment have answered the noise part of the question.

Comment: @gbulmer: I'm wrong, PGA204 has bigger gain range. And you mean i should put the PGA with bigger gain front, that say, PGA204 first ?

Comment: Yes, I think biggest gain PGA204 first. That is also my interpretation of Spehro Pefhany answer. I interpret pjc50 to be offering an even better suggestion; use a low noise amplifier, with fixed gain first because it looks like you *always* need *some* gain, and an LNA will give better noise results. However, I believe that Spehro Pefhany and pjc50 understand all this better than I do; I am only interpreting their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, certainly. The first amplifier will typically dominate the error and noise. If you have a PGA204 with gain of 1000 and the input offset is 50uV, then you could have 50mV of output offset from the first stage. Another gain of 300 would put the input offset beyond +/-15V rails. Same thing with noise. If your requirements allow you to AC couple the stages then you can get rid of the offset voltage issue, since each stage will only amplify its own offset. If you can band-limit the noise coming out of each stage then you can reduce the noise amplified by the next stage.

One possible reason to cascade such amplifiers is to get better frequency response by keeping the gain relatively low in each stage. The input-referred error and noise of each stage will generally be somewhat worse at low gains, of course.

Comment: I believe there is an error in the answer. The PGA205 is the lower gain device, and the PGA204 has the bigger gain range. Correct for that minor error, and I think I understand. I think  @pjc50's analysis that a fixed gain low-noise amplifier first, because the requirement seems to always need some gain, improves noise further, and maybe at lower cost.

Comment: @gbulmer True. I think you have to analyze noise spectrum and frequency response compared to requirements to decide what is best.